# Start Akeeba Backup Using a Cron Job

Tags: joomla, backup, cron-task

we are using Akeeba Backup for backing up our Joomla website. It is possible to start a backup just by calling an URL as described here: https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/quick-start-guide/automating-the-backup.html. To automate the backup of our site we want to call this URL using a daily executed Cron job. Our web hoster supports the creation of Cron jobs, but you cannot use any shell scripts or something. Only the execution of a PHP script is supported. So we have to call this URL using a PHP script. I created this script and it works fine when calling it directly using my browser. But when I try to execute it using the Cron job I only receive error 302, which means, that the document has temporarily moved. I don't know what to do with that. This is the script I want to execute:

```
<?php
    $result = file_get_contents("http://www.mysite.net/index.php?option=com_akeeba&view=backup&key=topsecret&format=r");
?>
```

I am not experienced with Cron jobs or PHP so any help would be nice.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to read [the documentation](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation/automating-your-backup.html). It tells you exactly how to use wget or curl for use with a CRON job. Moreover, there is a section called "A PHP alternative to wget". I write the documentation of Akeeba Backup and make available free of charge for a good reason: to be read and prevent such questions ;)

Comment: Neat! The first thing I was looking was the quick start guide, that's how I got the URL to call. After that I looked in the documentation also, but for some reason I did not read it to the end. Thanks for that.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately it does not work properly. When I execute the script "Sorry, the backup didn't work" is returned. I just copied the script from the documentation and changed the three parameters at the beginning of the script. The password is correct I checked it and also just called the URL via the browser and it seems to work there properly. Any ideas where I can look for an error description? I checked the log, but I found nothing there, but I can't say that I understood everything written in there.